# Запятая после скобок и др. вопросы

Tags: пунктуация

Вопросов несколько.

1) Нужна ли запятая после скобок?

2) Правильно ли поставлено тире?

3) Нужны ли кавычки при обозначении режима "открыть-закрыть"?

Два пневматических линейных привода для управления ножевыми задвижками (одна из задвижек работает в регулирующем режиме, а вторая — в режиме "открыть-­закрыть") с системой управления и возможностью   передачи    сигналов    в   диспетчерскую   посредством GSM были установлены на усреднительной камере ливневых стоков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, тире и кавычки поставлены верно.